# Change font size and width of select2 options

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

A little bit of context. I have a page that contains a table, where each column can be filtered. The filter inputs exist within the table, directly under the `th` tags. I am trying to add a select2 option to search and select multiple values for a certain column, Ticker. However, I am getting weird results with the select2 styling. Specifically, the select2 has text that is way to large, and the select is too narrow.

I am using Django, so there is a bit of templating within the Select tag

```
<td class='ticker-select' style='width: 150px'>
    <select id='{{heading}}-input' name='{{heading}}[]' class='filter filter-input form-control multi-select' style="width: 100%" multiple='multiple'>
        {% for ticker in tickers %}
            <option value='{{ticker}}' style='font-size: 10px;'>{{ticker}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</td>
```

There seems to be something that is causing an inline style to be attached to the input of the select.
The font size of the input and of the options is also being set to be way too big.

Unfortunately That is all I can provide for now, but if you need anything else please ask. 
I am using select2 4.0.12, as a CDN